# Simple form input type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, simple-form

I am using simple-form gem to render my forms. I am trying to set the input field type to 'number'. This code is not working:

```
f.input :amount, input_html: { type: 'number' }
```

What is the proper way to set this up?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The following should work

```
f.input :amount, input_html: { type: 'number' }
```

An even cleaner way would be:

```
f.input :amount, as: :numeric
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: This should be 'as: :numeric'

Comment: I updated the answer to be correct (and to use contemporary Ruby hash syntax). What's weird is that the code in the OP's question, `f.input :amount, input_html: { type: 'number' }`, actually does work. I personally prefer the `as: :numeric` version though.

Answer (score 10):

Simplest method:

```ruby
f.input :whatever, as: :numeric
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
f.input :amount, as: :integer
```